# How to infer the type of last element passed to `*args` parameter in python?

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

I want to write a `pipeline` function which takes an abritrary number of functions and forwards the input of the first to the second and so on up until the last. The output of `pipeline` is a `Callable`. The input of that `Callable` matches the first function given to `pipeline`. The output matches the last function given to `pipeline`. I would like to add type annotations to `pipeline`. This is what I came up with so far:

```py
from typing import TypeVar
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec, Concatenate

P = ParamSpec("P")
Output = TypeVar("Output")

def pipeline(func: Callable[Concatenate[P], T], *funcs: Callable[..., Output]) -> Callable[Concatenate[P], Output]:
    ...
```

But this gives a `Union` of all `Output` types of `*funcs`. Example:

```py
def double(x: int) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    return x, x*2

def add(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x + y

def to_string(x: int) -> str:
    return str(x)

new_func = pipeline(add, double, add, to_string)
```

With the type annotation shown above the type / signature of `new_func` results in

```py
new_func: (x: int, y: int) -> (Tuple[int, int] | int | str)
```

It's quite clear that pipeline should have the following signature:

```py
new_func: (x: int, y: int) -> str
```

Is there a way to achieve this with type annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually found a way to solve this problem using `TypeVarTuple` and `Unpack`. [PEP646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#args-as-a-type-variable-tuple) provides an example that shows how to unpack heterogenous parameters passed as `*args`. With this approach the example from the question could be typed as follows:

```py
from typing import TypeVar
from typing_extension import TypeVarTuple, ParamSpec, Unpack

Output = TypeVar("Output")
InputParams = ParamSpec("InputParams") 
IntermediateFunctions = TypeVarTuple("IntermediateFunctions")

def pipeline(*functions: Unpack[
  Tuple[
    Callable[InputParams, Any], 
    Unpack[IntermediateFunctions], 
    Callable[..., Output]
  ]
]) -> Callable[InputParams, Output]:
  ...

# From python 3.11 onwards you can use * instead of Unpack
def pipeline(*functions: *Tuple[Callable[InputParams, Any], *IntermediateFunctions, Callable[..., Output]]) -> Callable[InputParams, Output]:
  ...
```

Running mypy against this implementation failed as `Unpack` is not supported yet. I described the issue [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/13981)

Comment: Nice! Wrote my answer one day before 3.11 got released with `TypeVarTuple` and `Unpack` :D

Comment: Btw, I see that this implementation would build the signature of `new_func` correctly, but are you sure it would make sure that the passed functions are compatible with each other? So would it enforces that the return type of `add` matches the parameter type of `double` in `pipeline(add, double)`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure Python 3.10's type annotations are not powerful enough so you could define `pipeline` to support an arbitrary number of arguments. But, you could do it with overloads ([`@typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload)) and define `pipeline`'s signature separately for each arity.

You could take reference from the popular TypeScript library `fp-ts`, and more specifically from its `flow` function: https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/9da2137efb295b82fb59b7b0c2114f2ceb40a2b5/src/function.ts#L228-L351